# ignore output of 'broken pipe' signal

Tags: go

When executing a command (in Linux):

```
go run test.go |head
```

The output is:

```
line 0
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
signal: broken pipe
```

How to prevent the program from printing the signal notification (last line) ?

[BTW: even `2>/dev/null` dosn't work. probably the last line outputed to TTY]

Comment: Did you try `go run test.go 2> /dev/null | head`?

Comment: I did `go run test.go |head 2>/dev/null`

Comment: If writing to stdout returns an error, then exit the application.

Comment: It returns the `signal: broken pipe` line only when using with `|head`. How to catch that error ?

Comment: You catch the error just like any other in go. Show us the source to test.go if you're unsure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't print the code `test.go` so it is hard to judge.
For example does it sleep between prints?

Broken pipe would happpen because of a one of the programs in a chain of pipes:

```
a.exe|b.exe|c.exe|d.exe
```

terminates early. Either `test.go` terminates while head is still expecting 
input or more likely head terminates before  `test.go` finishes running. Especially since the default for head is  10 lines.

The test for that would be to do `go run test.go |head -20` and see if you get a broken pipe after printing 20.

I was not able to replicate this in C++, and don't know go. If it is the result of the go runtime, I suggest you try catching SIGPIPE in your code and terminating quietly. ( Doesn't matter what language really you, the process is the same the syntax different. )

Otherwise this is more a bash/zsh/whatever the shell du jour is. Before you run the command make a signal handler for SIGPIPE to exit cleanly.